# Prepend after ajax success

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My ajax success function doesn't execute the script after it has sent the data to my database, the data saves fine on my database but after that everything stops there. What might be wrong?

#### Javascript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".wall_update").click(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var boxval = $("#content").val();
        var dataString = 'content=' + boxval;


        $("#form1").validationEngine({
            type: "POST",
            ajaxSubmit: true,
            ajaxSubmitFile: "update_ajax.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                alert('success');
                $("ol#update").prepend(html);
                $("ol#update li:first").slideDown("slow");
                document.getElementById('content').value = '';
                $('#content').value = '';
                $('#content').focus();
                $("#flash").hide();

            }
        });

    });
});​
```

#### update_ajax.php

```
    <?php
    include("db.php");
    include("tolink.php");


    if(isSet($_POST['content']))

    {
    $id=time();//Demo Use

    $msg=$_POST['content']; 
    $date=date("M j, Y ");
    $sql=mysql_query("insert into appointments(message,date_sent)values('$msg','$date')");
    $result=mysql_query("select * from appointments order by msg_id desc");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $id=$row['msg_id'];
    $msg=$row['message'];
    $date=$row['date_sent'];

    $msg= nl2br($msg);
    $msg="<br>{$msg}<br>{$date}";
    }


    ?>




    <li class="bar<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <div align="left" class="post_box">
    <span style="padding:10px"><?php echo $msg; ?> </span>
    <span class="delete_button"><a href="#" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="delete_update">X</a></span>
    <span class='feed_link'><a href="#" class="comment" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">comment</a></span>
    </div>
    <div id='expand_box'>
    <div id='expand_url'></div>
    </div>
    <div id="fullbox" class="fullbox<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <div id="commentload<?php echo $id; ?>" >

    </div>
    <div class="comment_box" id="c<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <form method="post" action="" name="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <textarea class="text_area" name="comment_value" id="textarea<?php echo $id; ?>">
    </textarea><br />

<input type="submit" value=" Comment " class="comment_submit" id="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
</form>
</div>
</div>


</li>
```

#### HTML script

```
<div align="left">
<form  method="post" name="form" action="" id="form1">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500px">

<tr><td align="left"><div align="left"><h3>What are you doing?</h3></div></td></tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:4px; padding-left:10px;" class="update_box">
<textarea  class="validate[custom[last]] text-input" cols="30" rows="10" style="width:480px;font-size:14px; font-weight:bold" name="content" id="content"  ></textarea><br />
<input type="submit"  value="Update"  name="submit" class="wall_update"/>
</td>

</tr>

</table>
</form>

</div>

<ol  id="update" class="timeline">
// Display here after sending data to the database
</ol>
```

Comment: What happens if you alert (or use console.log) the `html` variable? Anything there?

Comment: Also, you're code is vunerable to MySQL injection attacks. Take a look at http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php

Comment: .valus is a DOM property and not a jQuery property .. If you want to use .value try this  $('#content')[0].value = '';

Comment: i know it's vulnerable it's just a prototype

Comment: Does the `alert('success');` fire?

Comment: no it does not fire but it does go yo update_ajax.php and sends the data to my database

Comment: If `validationEngine` offers an `error:` callback, give it a handler, and see if it fires.

Comment: @telexper. Well.. don't you think you should have mention it? what do you see in the console?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#content').value = '';
```

jQuery doesn't have a `value` property, you should use `val`:

```
$('#content').val('');
```

`value` is a property of the DOM Input object.

Comment: While that's true, it should be harmless here.